# Process the Object and store in efficient way

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, object

I receive an Object (**Object1**) with basic pattern of Key and value, And then I want to process and save **output** in MongoDB, such that it contain Array objects for "Locations" and "Address" which are dynamic in nature.

Please suggest me any efficient way to do that.

```js
const Object1 = { 
                        date:'07-Sep-2020',

                        Address_1_Ftime: 2,
                        Address_1_Rtime: 0,
                        Address_1_Stime: 49,

                        Address_2_Ftime: 12,
                        Address_2_Rtime: 40,
                        Address_2_Stime: 9

                        Location1Name:'SAV2',Location1Val:30,
                        Location2Name:'LT232',Location2Val:130,
                     }


const Output = 
{
    date : '07-Sep-2020',
    Address:
    [
        {
            name:'Address_1',
            Ftime:2,
            Rtime:0,
            Stime:49
        },
        {
            name:'Address_2',
            Ftime:12,
            Rtime:40,
            Stime:9
        }
    ],
    Locations:[
    {
        text:Location1,
        name:SAV2,
        value:30
    },
    {
        text:Location1,
        name:LT232,
        value:130
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I was using SQL server but I am jumped to MongoDB, so any suggestion/for saving this in structure would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's expected of you to show us what you have tried and others help when your attempts are not working as expected. SO is not a free code writing service

Comment: Okay, I will try this. Since this was my first question, so missed to ask professionally. Can you give any community/reference link to learn and do at my own.

Comment: Take a look at using Object.keys() and parsing the various key names

Comment: Question answered?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thomas for giving me direction, I was totally lost and was taking long time to do it.

Comment: okay no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you finish your trying, please check the following code.
And let me know if you are not following something there.

```js
const Object1 = { 
  date:'07-Sep-2020',

  Address_1_Ftime: 2,
  Address_1_Rtime: 0,
  Address_1_Stime: 49,

  Address_2_Ftime: 12,
  Address_2_Rtime: 40,
  Address_2_Stime: 9,

  Location1Name:'SAV2',Location1Val:30,
  Location2Name:'LT232',Location2Val:130,
};

// Initialize the output
const Output = {
  Address: {},
  Locations: {}
};

Object.keys(Object1).forEach(key => {
  const value = Object1[key];
  if (key === 'date') {
    Output.date = value;
  } else if (key.startsWith('Address')) {
    const addressName = key.substr(0, key.length - 6);
    const addressFieldKey = key.substr(key.length - 5);
    Output.Address[addressName] = Output.Address[addressName] || {};
    Output.Address[addressName][addressFieldKey] = value;
  } else if (key.startsWith('Location')) {
    const fieldKeyLength = key.endsWith('Name') ? 4 : 3;
    const locationName = key.substr(0, key.length - fieldKeyLength);
    const locationFieldKey = key.substr(key.length - fieldKeyLength);
    Output.Locations[locationName] = Output.Locations[locationName] || {};
    Output.Locations[locationName][locationFieldKey] = value;
  }
});

// At this point, Address and Locations of Output are still objects not array. So you need the following change.

Output.Address = Object.keys(Output.Address).map(key => ({
  name: key,
  ...Output.Address[key]
}));

Output.Locations = Object.keys(Output.Locations).map(key => ({
  text: key,
  name: Output.Locations[key].Name,
  value: Output.Locations[key].Val
}));

console.log(Output);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is very useful for a fresh person like me. So nice of you.